# How to resolve conflict in vscode

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

When I develop apps in vscode, I tried `git pull`.

And then I `Accept Both Change`

Therefore now , Both changes are reflected.

But it seems that it has still conflict as displayed in attached file.

Why is this occured.

As I am git beginner,I'd like to know how to resolve conflict in  vscode.

Why the conflict still remain ?

[image]

If someone has opinion,please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: If you don't mind getting out of your comfort zone, take a look at http://ezconflict.com/en/conflicts.html. my material, no tracking, no monetizing.

Comment: look in the file and see if you notice conflict markers, they will stand out, remove them by fixing the code and conflict is gone

Comment: @rioV8's comment is the ultimate short description of what it is about.... but it's got details.... **many** details. That's what I try to tackle with my site.